# Error after importing pandas in simple python script

Tags: python, pandas, malloc

so basically I just create a virtualenv and after run `pip install pandas` and try to run my script this error jumps out:

[image]

I don't understand, the error is in the grist line when I import pandas.. if I just remove this line... the script works as usual

What can I do ???
Help Pls!

These are my versions:
[image]

Update:

Error as Text:

```
Python(25555,0x110fc3dc0) malloc: can't allocate region
:*** mach_vm_map(size=18446744071807086592, flags: 100) failed (error code=3)
Python(25555,0x110fc3dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
init_dgelsd failed init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/deivbid/Documents/David/Python/Scrapper/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Users/deivbid/Documents/David/Python/Scrapper/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "/Users/deivbid/Documents/David/Python/Scrapper/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 286, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Polyfit sanity test emitted a warning, most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend. If you compiled yourself, see site.cfg.example for information. Otherwise, report this to the vendor that provided NumPy.
RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned
```

Python Version: 3.9.0
pip version: 20.2.3

Comment: Please include your errors [as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), not pictures.

Comment: updated, but please help me

Comment: Is numpy installed in your venv? If so, what version of numpy is installed?

Comment: It seems like it is unable to find numpy as @It_is_Chris is alluding to. What happens if you put `import numpy as np` in a file (without trying to import pandas)

Comment: Let me try with that and I'll reply here

Comment: Ok to reply to @It_is_Chris Yes I have numpy and the version is 1.19.2

and to reply to @noah if I remove the line of `import pandas as pd` and I replaced for `import numpy as np` it throws the exact same error 

I don't get it !

Answer (score 1):

got the same error and found this : https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15947

For me
pip3 install numpy==1.18.0
solved the problem